# Clojure iOS Development

Tags: ios, clojure, cross-compiling

Over the past months, I've pretty much fallen in love with Clojure and refuse to use anything else.

I am aware that there is ClojureScript, which uses Google Closure to compile a subset of Clojure to JavaScript.

Is there anything similar in the works for Objective-C/Cocoa?

I would love to be able to prototype applications in Clojure, and then get an iOS app out of it.

[I'm perfectly fine if this prevents me from all the low level details of iOS -- I don't need access to any low level details (say pointer arithmetic) that I can't do in Java -- I just want to be able to easily transform my Clojure Apps onto the iOS]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run clojure on iOS by compiling clojure to scheme, https://github.com/takeoutweight/clojure-scheme

Answer (score 10):

There's one more option (warning: haven't tried it yet):
https://github.com/oakes/lein-fruit
This Leiningen plugin translates Java bytecode to native code for iOS. And there's even IDE that has it built-in:
https://github.com/oakes/Nightcode

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered [las3r](https://github.com/aemoncannon/las3r/wiki) which is a Clojure port to the ActionScript (the language behind Flash) runtime. Since Flash/ActionScript can now develop for iOS (I'm in the process of writing a game right now. It's not wonderful, but it's quite usable), this may present a path to writing Clojure applications for iOS.

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tried this. I've just barely discovered las3r, haven't even downloaded it. and have no idea if it's good or terrible. I don't know how awful the speed will be. I know *nothing*.

Still - it's an intriguing idea, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Re-Natal](https://github.com/drapanjanas/re-natal) a simple command-line utility that automates most of the process of setting up a React Native app running on ClojureScript.